# Jasmine/Karma Component Test In Angular 2 Not Working

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, systemjs

I'm trying to configure testing on my new Angular 2 application (2.0.0-rc.1)

I can run tests that don't use any components defined outside the test file itself ( moving the component class inside the test file works)

Once I try to "new" or use TestComponentBuilder on a component located outside the test file, it blows up.

It seems to be requesting, fetching and serving both the test file (helloworld.spec.js) and the component file (hello.component2.js)

I've seen that this error usually means something that is needed, isn't loading, but it appears that all the files are loaded.

```
19 05 2016 08:00:01.319:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/demo/hello/helloworld.spec.js /
19 05 2016 08:00:01.319:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching D:/web/app/demo/hello/helloworld.spec.js
19 05 2016 08:00:01.320:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): D:/web/app/demo/hello/helloworld.spec.js
19 05 2016 08:00:01.384:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/demo/hello/hello.component2.js /
19 05 2016 08:00:01.385:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching D:/web/app/demo/hello/hello.component2.js
19 05 2016 08:00:01.386:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): D:/web/app/demo/hello/hello.component2.js
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function
    at C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\reporter.js:45:23
    at onBrowserError (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\base.js:58:60)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at onKarmaError (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:95:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MDn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.onevent (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io-parser\index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (C:\Users\MD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:175:18)
```

---

karma.conf

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher')
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      '**/app/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage'],
      '**/demo/**/!(*spec).js' : ['coverage']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/',
      includeAllSources: true
    },
    customLaunchers: {
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

files: [
  { pattern: 'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js', included: true, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js', included: true, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js', included: true, watched: false },

  { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js', included: true, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js', included: true, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js', included: true, watched: false},

  { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*', included: false, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*', included: false, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'systemjs.config.test.js', included: true, watched: true },

  // Distribution folder.

  { pattern: 'app/**/*', included: false, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'common/**/*', included: false, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'common/utils/**/*', included: false, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'common/utils/logger/**/*', included: false, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'demo/**/*', included: false, watched: true }
],
exclude: [
  // Vendor packages might include spec files. We don't want to use those.
  //'dist/vendor/**/*.spec.js'
],
reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
port: 9877,
colors: true,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false


 });
};
```

---

karma-test-shim.js

```
/*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

__karma__.loaded = function () {
};

var distPath = '/base/';
var appPath = distPath;

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-8) == '.spec.js';
}

function isAppFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, appPath.length) == appPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isAppFile);

// Load our SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
   baseURL: distPath
});

System.import('systemjs.config.test.js').then(function() {
  // Load and configure the TestComponentBuilder.
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ]).then(function (providers) {
    var testing = providers[0];
    var testingBrowser = providers[1];

    testing.setBaseTestProviders(testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
      testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
  });
}).then(function() {
  // Finally, load all spec files.
  // This will run the tests directly.
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    }));
}).then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```

---

systemjs.config.test.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 * Override at the last minute with global.filterSystemConfig (as plunkers do)
 */
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app/', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap' :              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap',
    'moment' :                    'node_modules/moment/moment'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'demo':                       {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',

    '@angular/upgrade'
  ];

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

---

test file

```
import {
    beforeEachProviders,
    describe,
    expect,
    it,
    inject,
    injectAsync
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    TestComponentBuilder, ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import {HelloAppComponent2} from "./hello.component2";

beforeEachProviders(() => {});

describe('NetX - Hello World App', () => {

    //DOESN'T WORK
    it('should run basic test', () => {
        var myComp = new HelloAppComponent2();
        console.log("HelloWorld Test promise resolved.");
        console.log("Hello World Test");
        expect("HelloWorld").toEqual("HelloWorld");
    });

    /*
        ALSO DOESN'T WORK
     it('should run basic test', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
         return tcb.createAsync(HelloAppComponent2).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
             console.log("HelloWorld Test promise resolved.");
             componentFixture.detectChanges();
             console.log("Hello World Test");
             expect("HelloWorld").toEqual("HelloWorld");
         });
     }));
     */

    /*
    THIS TEST BELOW WORKS FINE.
    it('should run basic test', () => {
        console.log("Hello World Test");
        expect("HelloWorld").toEqual("HelloWorld");
    });
    */

});
```

Comment: I figured it out!  It has something to do with the coverage reporter.  If I take out the coverage reporter, the tests work fine!  Now will try to figure out why the coverage reporter is bombing.